# how to slice the tensorflow tensor to multiple

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, slice

the tensor is:
batch(3) * length(5) * dim(2)

```
tensor = tf.constant([[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5]],[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5]],[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5]]] )
```

and i want get more slices by length_index [0,0],[0,1] ... [3,4],[4,4] according to length_axis_index[0,1,2,3,4],the operation like

```
spans_length=0
with tf.variable_scope("loss_span"):
    output=[]
    for i in range(0,1+n_spans):
        for j in range(1,seq_length):
            if j + i < seq_length:
                res = tf.slice(output_layer_sequence, [0, j, 0], [-1, j+i-j+1, -1])
                res = tf.reduce_sum(res,axis=1)
                output.append(res)
                # output = tf.convert_to_tensor(output)
                spans_length+=1

    output = tf.convert_to_tensor(output)
    vsp = tf.transpose(output, [1,0,2])#batch , spans_length,hidden_size
    vsp = tf.reshape(vsp,[-1,hidden_size])#batch * span_length,hidden_size
    span_logits = tf.matmul(vsp, output_span_weight, transpose_b=True)  # output:[batch * spans_length,class_labels]
    span_logits = tf.nn.bias_add(span_logits, output_span_bias)  # output:[batch * spans_length,class_labels]
    span_matrix = tf.reshape(span_logits,[-1,spans_length,class_labels],name="span_matrix_val")#[batch , spans_length,class_labels]
    
   
    label_span_logists = tf.one_hot(indices=label_span,depth=class_labels, on_value=1, off_value=0, axis=-1, dtype=tf.int32)
    label_span_logists=tf.cast(label_span_logists,tf.int64)
    span_loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=span_matrix, labels=label_span_logists)
    span_loss = tf.reduce_mean(span_loss, name='loss_span')
```

when i doing such operation, training model 's time is very long;how to speed it.thanks

Comment: please clarify - what does `slice(0,0)` mean. Is it `tensor[:,0,0]` ? Or `tensor[:,0:0,:] ?

Comment: slice(0,0) means a1=tf.slice(tensor,[0,0,0],[-1,0,-1]))
slice(0,1) means a2=tf.slice(tensor,[0,0,0],[-1,1,-1]))
slice(0,2) means a3=tf.slice(tensor,[0,0,0],[-1,2,-1])),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works:

```
# tensor = tf.constant([[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5]],[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5]],[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5]]] )
tensor = tf.random.uniform((3, 2000, 2))
length = tf.shape(tensor)[1].numpy()
output = []
for begins in range(length):
  for size in range(length - begins):
    res = tf.slice(tensor, [0, begins, 0], [-1, size + 1, -1])
    res = tf.reduce_sum(res)
    output.append(res)
output = tf.convert_to_tensor(output)
```

I tried to use `tf.scan()`, but I don't see any benefits:

```
output = tf.constant([], tf.int32)
for begins in range(length):
  t = tensor[:, begins:, :]
  t = tf.transpose(t, (1, 0, 2))
  t = tf.scan(lambda a, x: a + x, t)
  t = tf.transpose(t, (1, 0, 2))
  t = tf.reduce_sum(t, [0, 2])
  output = tf.concat([output, t], 0)
```

**Edits:**

Tried to apply `reduce_sum()` along the unused dimension [0, 2] in preprocessing:

```
tensor = tf.reduce_sum(tensor, [0, 2])
output = tf.constant([])
for begins in range(length):
  t = tensor[begins:]
  t = tf.scan(lambda a, x: a + x, t)
  output = tf.concat([output, t], 0)
```

Still don't see performance benefits.

Comment: when i doing such operation, training time is very long;how to speed it.thanks 
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/66011043/8375120

Comment: @Colt see edits. I don't think it is possible to significantly improve - the bottleneck is `scan()` and I doubt that it is possible to calculate accumulated sums faster than `scan()`

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0,50):
    for j in range(1,200):
         if j + i < 200:
            res = tf.slice(output_layer_sequence, [0, j, 0], [-1, j+i-j+1, -1])
            res = tf.reduce_sum(res,axis=1)
            output.append(res)
output = tf.convert_to_tensor(output)
```

when i doing such operation, training time is very long;how to speed it.thanks